# How long does it take to report a crash?

Tags: ios8, crashlytics

I recently setup Crashlytics, and although there have been times where my beta users will crash the app and i'll get back a report, I feel like i'm not always getting back all the crashes.

Today, for example, I deliberately inserted into my viewDidLoad a line that will crash (array index out of bounds exception) and after 2 hours I still didn't see this particular error in my list.

Is there some sort of wait time (like 24 hours) before you see the error?
I can't conclude that "crashlytics isn't working ever" because I *do* see error reports sometimes, but i'm not confident it's always working.

in app delegate:

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {

  Fabric.with([Crashlytics()])
  ....
  Crashlytics.sharedInstance().setUserName(userSettings.UserName)
 }
```

and then in my view controller, I have:

```
   Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()
```

Is it right to do Crashlytics.sharedInstance? Maybe that's trying to get a difference / wrong instance of my application? I didn't see a way of doing it with "Fabric"

Thanks!

Comment: Hey there, Mike from Crashlytics here. A couple of things could be causing crash reports to now show up right away!

Crash reports are sent on relaunch of the app so be sure to launch the app after causing a crash. XCode's debugger also needs to be disconnected - here are steps to do that: http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/92523-why-can-t-i-have-xcode-connected

Comment: Hey Mike thanks for getting back to me. I updated my question above to show what I had in app delegate, and what I had when I crash (in another view controller). Is this right? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, that setup looks good. Were you testing on simulator or a device? Also, feel free to email me at support (at) crashlytics (dot) com and I can dig into our backend for your specific app.

Comment: was trying on the simulator - do you think that could be it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK so this was some stupidity on my part. I read that you need to detach the debugger but what I didn't understand (no one laugh at me) was that you need to stop it (obviously) by pressing the square stop button in Xcode(obviously), but THEN keep the simulator open (the other program that starts obviously) and click on your app's icon from the simulator "home screen".

So you start the app in Xcode w/ debugging, then crash it, then stop, then re-start your app from the simulator (not from Xcode itself by pressing play) and then it should send your report.

Also just a big thanks to the Crashlytics team for their support. Mike reached out to me directly and helped me get setup :)